# How do I configure WildFly's messaging-activemq subsystem to create JMS connections using the server hostname rather than an IP address?

Tags: ssl, jms, wildfly, activemq-artemis, wildfly-26

I have an application running on WildFly 26.1.3 that I've been securing to use only HTTPS. I've got almost everything sorted out, except for the JMS connections generated by the `messaging-activemq` subsystem. Any remote JMS connection objects created from this subsystem use the IP address of my server instead of the hostname or fully qualified domain name for the connection URL. My SSL certificates don't like that.

Example client java code where I see the problem:

```java
// Using JNDI to get a TopicConnectionFactory from the Wildfly server
Hashtable<String, String> p = new Hashtable<String, String>();
p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "https://<serverFQDN>:9090");
Context jndiContext;
jndiContext = new InitialContext(p);

myTopicConnFac = (TopicConnectionFactory)jndiContext.lookup(topicConnFacName); // JNDI look up succeeds

myTopicConnection = myTopicConnFac.createTopicConnection(); // Throws SSL connection error due to IP address usage
```

Is there a configuration option I can use to instruct the `TopicConnectionFactory` to use the hostname instead of the IP address for this?

Here are the pertinent pieces of my `standalone.xml`:

```xml
    ...
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:13.1">
            <server name="default">
                <statistics enabled="${wildfly.messaging-activemq.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}"/>
                <security enabled="false"/>
                <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10"/>
                <http-connector name="https-connector" socket-binding="https" endpoint="https-acceptor">
                    <param name="ssl-enabled" value="true"/>
                </http-connector>
                <http-connector name="https-connector-throughput" socket-binding="https" endpoint="https-acceptor-throughput">
                    <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                </http-connector>
                <http-acceptor name="https-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
                <http-acceptor name="https-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
                    <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                    <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
                </http-acceptor>
                ...
                <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" retry-interval="1000" reconnect-attempts="1000" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory java:jboss/exported/com.rsc.mmpl.TopicConnectionFactory java:jboss/exported/com.rsc.mmpl.Log4jTopicConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
            </server>
       <subsystem/>
    ...
    <interfaces>
        ...
        <!-- jboss.bind.address is set to the server's FQDN, not IP address -->
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>
    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        ...
        <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:9090}"/>
        ...
    </socket-binding-group>
```

I've tried adding several different parameters (local-address, host, hostname) to the `http-connector` section, to no avail.

Comment: Did you start Wildfly with `-b 0.0.0.0` option ?

Comment: From my understanding, `-b 0.0.0.0` would bind WildFly to every IP address available to the server's ethernet card. I don't believe that is necessary or would help, considering the Artemis ActiveMQ client can connect to the server with the IP address, it's the SSL step that blocks it because the IP address isn't on the server's certificate. My workplace doesn't want to put the IP address on the certificate and I'm trying to find a way to comply. (I'm really starting to think this isn't possible with Artemis ActiveMQ embedded in WildFly)

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming that you are running behind a firewall. You need to follow the guide on the full set of changes needed for running behind NAT

Comment: There is no firewall between the client and the server, they run in the same subnet. The client and server do not run in the same VM however, so an InVM transport isn't possible

Comment: By default the connection factory will use the bind address unless configured otherwise. Even though you aren't behind nat you face the same issue, you don't want to connect using the bind IP but a hostname supplied by yourself

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html/configuring_messaging/acceptors_and_connectors